# How do I build up towards a velocity by using add force?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have bean trying to create a **script** to move an **object** with `Rigidbody.AddForce`.

My goal is to reach a **specified velocity** by just **adding force**.

I have some **if statements** that allow **three scenarios**:

- If the player doesn't reach over desired velocity after adding force: *Add force*
- If the player doesn't reach over desired velocity after subtracting force: *Subtract force*
- If the player is closer than the add force jumps: *Add exact force to maintain velocity*

However I wasn't able to create the desired outcome.

Currently as soon as it comes close to the **desired velocity** it jumps between above and below the **desired velocity** rapidly.

I think this is because my **calculation to predict the next velocity** is not accurate.

I was trying to tweak it in multiple ways but I simply can't figure out how to get it right.

It may be possible that there is a **different cause** to my problem, but if so, I can't find it.

Anyway I put my code below.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public partial class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    //*Public
    //Targeted Objects
    /// <summary>The camera stand/parent/folder that is used for left and right 
    /// rotations</summary>
    public GameObject cameraPivotRL;

    /// <summary>The camera stand/parent/folder that is used for gravity related 
    /// rotations</summary>
    public GameObject cameraGravityPivot;

    //Target scripts
    /// <summary>A script that reads inputs</summary>
    public PlayerInputs playerInputs;

    //User settings
    //speed settings
    /// <summary>The amount the player accelerates</summary>
    public float accelerationForce;

    /// <summary>The amount the player decelerates</summary>
    public float decelerationForce;

    /// <summary>The players desired velocity</summary>
    public float desiredVelocity;

    /// <summary>How fast the velocity will reach the desired velocity after  
    /// accelerating or decelerating</summary>
    public float approximationSpeed;


    //*Private
    //Inputs
    /// <summary>Directional inputs used for Moving the character</summary>
    private Vector2 moveInput;
    /// <summary>Magnitude/lengt of the moveInput Vector</summary>
    private float moveInputMagni;

    //Camera pivot R/L Vectors (I use the camera stand so it's not influenced by 
    //up/down rotations)
    /// <summary>The forward vector of the camera</summary>
    private Vector3 camF;
    /// <summary>The right vector of the camera</summary>
    private Vector3 camR;

    //Gravity pivot Vector
    /// <summary>The vector opposed to the gravity direction</summary>
    private Vector3 gravityPivot;

    //Physics
    /// <summary>The Unity component which stores and processes the players 
    /// physics</summary>
    private Rigidbody body;
    /// <summary>The players current velocity</summary>
    private float bodyVelocityMagnitude;

    /// <summary>The portion of the players velocity that is going in the desired 
    /// direction</summary>
    private float veloInDesiredDirectionMagni;

    /// <summary>The velocity the player is predicted to have after applying the 
    /// acceleration force</summary>
    private float predictedVelocity;

    //Debug bools
    private bool isAccelerating = false;
    private float isAcceleratingForce;
    private bool isDecelerating = false;
    private float isDeceleratingForce;
    private bool isMaximizing = false;
    private float isMaximizingForce;

    /// <summary>The force that will be applied</summary>
    private float desiredForceMagni;
    /// <summary>The amount of velocity that will be added after force is 
    /// applied</summary>
    private float addedVeloMagni;
    /// <summary>The velocity from the previous step</summary>
    private float velocityMagniMem;
    /// <summary>The difference betwean the current velocity and the previous 
    /// velocity</summary>
    private float velocityChange;

    /// <summary>a simple bool to keep track of when this code is ran</summary>
    private bool stepCheck = false;

    //#### Unity Functions ####
    //## Awake is called when this object is spawned
    private void Awake()
    {
        //Get rigidbody
        body = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

        //Get input script
        playerInputs = GetComponent<PlayerInputs>();
    }

    //## Fixed update is called 50 times per second
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //Reset debug bools
        isAccelerating = false;
        isDecelerating = false;
        isMaximizing = false;

        //Draw current velocity
        Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), 
                body.velocity * 0.1f, Color.white);

        //Measure the current velocity
        bodyVelocityMagnitude = body.velocity.magnitude;

        //Get move inputs
        moveInput = playerInputs.moveInput;

        //* Main move script block
        if (moveInput.magnitude > 0)
        {
            //Get camera axis
            camF = cameraPivotRL.transform.forward;
            camR = cameraPivotRL.transform.right;

            //Get the current gravity direction
            gravityPivot = cameraGravityPivot.transform.up;

            //Turn inputs into a direction relative to the camera
            var desiredDirection = (camF * moveInput.y) + (camR * moveInput.x);

            //Determine the dirctional force that will be applied
            var desiredForce = desiredDirection * accelerationForce;

            //Calculate how much velocity will be added after the force is applied
            var addedVelo = desiredForce.normalized * (desiredForce.magnitude 
                    - (body.velocity.magnitude * body.drag)) / body.mass 
                    * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            //Calculate how much of the current velocity is going in the desired 
            //direction
            var veloInDesiredDirection = body.velocity - (body.velocity 
                    - desiredDirection.normalized * Vector3.Dot(body.velocity, 
                    desiredDirection.normalized));

            //Make the desired velocity shrink/grow based on the move inputs 
            //strengt
            var desiredVelocityTemp = desiredVelocity * moveInput.magnitude;

            //Predict future velocity and add/subtract force accordingly
            //will velocity in the desired direction be greater or ecual to 
            //desired velocity after aplying force?
            if ((addedVelo + veloInDesiredDirection).magnitude 
                    >= desiredVelocityTemp && veloInDesiredDirection.magnitude 
                    >= desiredVelocityTemp && Vector3.Dot(body.velocity, 
                    desiredDirection.normalized) > 0)
            {
                //will velocity in the desired direction still be greater than
                //desired velocity after aplying negative force?
                if (((addedVelo * -1) + veloInDesiredDirection).magnitude 
                        > desiredVelocityTemp)
                {
                    //apply force in oposite direction of desired direction
                    body.AddForce(desiredForce * -1, ForceMode.Acceleration);

                    //a peace of code to measure how much the velocity changed
                    //after 1 step
                    if (stepCheck && velocityMagniMem > 0)
                    {
                        velocityChange = body.velocity.magnitude 
                                - velocityMagniMem;
                        stepCheck = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        velocityMagniMem = body.velocity.magnitude;
                        stepCheck = true;
                    }

                    //Debug
                    //draw ray that represents the negative force that is applied 
                    //to the player
                    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, desiredForce * -1 * 0.005f, 
                            Color.cyan);

                    //this code is running
                    isDecelerating = true;

                    //measure force
                    isDeceleratingForce = desiredForce.magnitude * -1;
                }
                else
                {
                    //calculate force requered to reach and maintain velocity
                    var requiForce = (desiredVelocityTemp * 1.4056579f 
                        + 20.6009236f) * (((desiredVelocityTemp 
                        - (desiredDirection.normalized * Vector3.Dot(
                        body.velocity, desiredDirection.normalized)).magnitude) 
                        * approximationSpeed) + 1);

                    //apply force needed to reach and maintain desired velocity
                    body.AddForce(desiredForce.normalized * requiForce,
                            ForceMode.Acceleration);

                    //Debug
                    //draw ray that represents the negative force that is applied 
                    //to the player
                    Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, desiredForce.normalized 
                            * requiForce * 0.005f, Color.green);

                    //this code is running
                    isMaximizing = true;

                    //measure force
                    isMaximizingForce = requiForce;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //apply force in desired direction
                body.AddForce(desiredForce, ForceMode.Acceleration);

                //a peace of code to measure how much the velocity changed after 
                //1 step
                if (stepCheck && velocityMagniMem > 0)
                {
                    velocityChange = body.velocity.magnitude - velocityMagniMem;
                    stepCheck = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    velocityMagniMem = body.velocity.magnitude;
                    stepCheck = true;
                }

                //Debug
                //draw ray that represents the negative force that is applied to 
                //the player
                Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, desiredForce * 0.005f, 
                        Color.red);

                //this code is running
                isAccelerating = true;

                //measure force
                isAcceleratingForce = desiredForce.magnitude;
            }

            //Code to turn player model
            //if velocity is detected use velocity to turn player model
            if(body.velocity.magnitude > 0.01f)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(camF * Vector3.Dot(
                        camF, body.velocity.normalized) + camR * Vector3.Dot(camR,
                        body.velocity.normalized), gravityPivot);
            }
            //if not use inputs
            else if(moveInput.magnitude > 0)
            {
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation((camF * moveInput.y) 
                        + (camR * moveInput.x), gravityPivot);
            }

            //Debug variables
            //the strengt of the applied force
            desiredForceMagni = desiredForce.magnitude;

            //the amount of velocity that is predicted to be added after aplying 
            //force
            addedVeloMagni = addedVelo.magnitude;

            //the current velocity strengt that is in the same direction as the
            //desired direction
            veloInDesiredDirectionMagni = veloInDesiredDirection.magnitude;

            //the velocity streng that is predected player is predicted to have in 
            //the desired direction after force is applied
            predictedVelocity = (addedVelo + veloInDesiredDirection).magnitude;

            //draw predicted velocity
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.2f, 0), 
                    addedVelo.normalized * predictedVelocity * 0.1f, 
                    Color.magenta);

            //draw the velocity in the desired direction
            Debug.DrawRay(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0), 
                    veloInDesiredDirection * 0.1f, Color.yellow);

            //draw a line betwean the normal velocity and the velocity in the 
            //desired direction
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0) 
                    + (veloInDesiredDirection * 0.1f), transform.position 
                    + new Vector3(0, 0.1f, 0) + (body.velocity * 0.1f), 
                    Color.gray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At this point you probably jsut want to find mistake you made i nway you worked.. but...Arent you overcomplicating this for yourself? you just want velocity capped ; you don't need to know how much to add. if velocity on each axis exeeeds desired value  then velocity equals maximum value( or negative maximum value). do it for each axis and thats al lyou need to get desired effect.

Comment: I don't really want to cap it.
I want it to try reach and maintain the desired velocity gradually.

Comment: for example: if the desired velocity is 10 it will work up towards it.
if the desired velocity is zero it should work down towards it.
same thing for when it goes faster than the desired velocity. 

also i want to determine the incrediment/decrediment speed my self.

Comment: Please use the correct tags. `[unityscript]` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in previous Unity versions and is long**deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly in `c#`

Comment: You should not have public fields but public properties(https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/161303/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-public-fields) and (https://www.ndepend.com/default-rules/NDepend-Rules-Explorer.html?ruleid=ND1805#!); furthermore you can add check/cap/"compute final velocity" code in those properties.

Comment: Have you tested how accurate `addedVelo` is when you simply add `desiredForce`?

Comment: If the velocity is of a huge magnitude perpendicular to desired direction with small magnitude, should it use acceleration or deceleration force? question unclear

Comment: @derHugo 

The tags are already gone.

I don't know how, but I will keep what you sad in mind for the next time.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot

I tried but Unity doesn't allow me to use normal properties.

If I use those instead of fields Unity wont read them and I cant change them in the editor.

Comment: @Ruzihm

I have tested it and it's not accurate at all, but I don't know how to make it accurate.

Comment: @Ruzihm 

To your second question: 

When the velocity is higher than the desired velocity it should use deceleration force

Comment: Here https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.properties@0.4/manual/index.html I can see properties; anyway it's c#, there are properties (auto-prop from c# 3.0 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties). So what you describe is unexpected; however, I don't know unity3d and its specificities.

Comment: @Soleil-MathieuPrévot Ah thanks, but I can't find the Property API. I supose Unity does things in the Unity way.

Comment: @Magic-4e What does it mean for a velocity to be *higher*? you mean the magnitude? So if desired Velocity is 10 units up, and current velocity is 5 units down, it should be using acceleration force to change because the magnitude is smaller? this seems weird to me.

Comment: @Ruzihm Yes I mean magnitude. But no to decrease its (magnitude) it must decelerate and to increase it it must accelerate.
Although at the moment I don't use the deceleration variable and temporarily use the acceleration variable for both instead. I just use it in reverse for deceleration.

Answer (score 4):

I have found what I was looking for.
So here for everyone else struggling with this:

```
//Set a target velocity
Vector3 targetVelocity = moveDirection * maxSpeed;

//Find the change of velocity needed to reach target
Vector3 velocityChange = targetVelocity - rb.velocity;

//Convert to acceleration, which is change of velocity over time
Vector3 acceleration = velocityChange / Time.fixedDeltaTime;

//Clamp it to your maximum acceleration magnitude
acceleration = Vector3.ClampMagnitude(acceleration, maxAcceleration);

//Then AddForce
rb.AddForce(acceleration, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```

I hope this will help someone else too.